# iOS CoreData objects access while a statement is running

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobject

I have a fairly large database that I query through and I want my app to be showing responses as they are found. So I start doing the search on another thread, and keep updating my on the main thread through the tableview.
Now, the problem is, when my searching thread is running a statemtn (to find the next batch of results) my tableview cells can't be created because I can't access any coredata objects while a statement is running!
What do I do?
I have considered getting all the results out of my ManagedDataObjects before running the next query but that's just messy. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your background thread package up an NSArray of `NSManagedObjectID`s, then have your main thread use those to directly get the set of objects for display.